# Selenium javascript automating gmail login

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to automate the login process in gmail using selenium and javascript as programming language:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);
client
    .init()
    .url('https://mail.google.com/')
    .pause(2000)
    .setValue('input#identifierId', 'petruuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu')
    .pause(2000)
    .click('div#identifierNext')
    .pause(2000)
    .setValue('input.whsOnd.zHQkBf', 'petru123') //the program blocks here
    .pause(2000)
    .click('div#passwordNext')
    .end();
```

The problem is that the program is blocking at the line
      `.setValue('input.whsOnd.zHQkBf', 'petru123')`

If I comment it, the div with the id `'passwordNext'`  is clicked, just as desired. What should be the problem/ what should I check?

Comment: you realize google uses something called captcha yes?

Comment: @William yes, irrelevant in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use attribute values that are generated randomly, for password you could use a css selector like this:

```
input[type=password]
```

resulting in:

```
.setValue('input[type=password]', 'petru123')
```

Comment: mersi frumos :)